# how ->find('threaded') can work with cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use tree behavior for category table. I just created `model`, `controller`, `categoryTable`, `category.php` using cake Bake. it's working but I'm trying to put all child under his parent, after reading cakebake book I come to know that `->find('threaded')`  could do this. But it is giving error.

Error is:

> Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead

The full query is:

```
$parentCategory = $this->Category->ParentCategory->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->find('threaded');
```

It is giving error but if I remove `->find('threaded')` then no error but it display data in same order as it saves.

Currently it is working as follows;

```
Parent 1
child 1
child 2

Parent 2
child 1
child 2
child 3(from parent 1)
```

While I want to display as given below

```
parent 1
child 1 
child 2
child 3

parent 2
child 1
child 2
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$parentCategories = $this -> Categories -> ParentCategories -> find('treeList', ['limit' => 200]);
```

All models in cakephp3 must be in prulars

*Category* should be *Categories* and *ParentCategory* should be *ParentCategories*